# ElasticSearch - How create Index template/mapping per alias and perform search against each alias separately

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Is is any way in elastic to store index template per alias.
I mean create Index with multiple aliases (alias1 ,alias2 ..) and attach different template to each of them. Then perform Index/Search docs on specific alias.

The reason I'm doing so due to multiple different data-structure (up to 50 types) of documents.

What I did so far is :

```
 1. PUT /dynamic_index

 2. POST /_aliases
       { "actions" : [
        { "add" : { "index" : "dynamic_index", "alias" : "alias_type1" } },
        { "add" : { "index" : "dynamic_index", "alias" : "alias_type2" } },
        { "add" : { "index" : "dynamic_index", "alias" : "alias_type3" } }
        ]}
 3. 

    PUT_template/template1 {
      "index_patterns": [
        "dynamic_index"
      ],
      "mappings": {
        "dynamic_templates": [
          {
            "strings_as_keywords": {
              "match_mapping_type": "string",
              "mapping": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "standard",
                "copy_to": "_all",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "properties": {
          "source": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "aliases": {
        "alias_type1": {
        }
      }
    }

4. same way to alias_type2 , alias_type3 but different fields ...
```

Indexing/Search : Trying create and search docs per alias like in example:

```
   POST alias_type1/_doc
    {
      "source": "foo" 
     , .....
      
    }

    POST alias_type2/_doc
    {
      "source": "foo123" 
     , .....
      
    }
    
    GET alias_type1/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      }
    }
  GET alias_type2/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      }
    }
```

What I see actually that even if I index documents per alias,
when searching I don't see result per alias ,all results are same on alias_type1,2 and even on index.

Any way I can achieve separation logic on each alias in terms of searches/index docs per type (alias) ?

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You can’t have separate mapping for aliases pointing to the same index! Aliases are like virtual link pointing to a index so if your aliases pointing to same index you will get the same result back.
If you want to have different mapping based on your data structure you will need to creat multiple indices.

**Update**
You also can use custom routing based on a field for more information you can check Elastic official documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html).

Comment: Thanks, Maybe Can I apply multiple templates on 1 index (no aliases) ? And give somehow elastic to choose which template to use according to incoming document?

Comment: It is not possible but why not you are making a field identifying document type in one index, and why not if you have different type of documents using multiple indices instead.

Comment: Because in specific types we have very very small amount of data like up to 10k documents,  while on other indices could be huge about 500M , and im afraid  of inbalancing / cluster performance. This is the reason I think to put all in 1 index with different  mappings ..

Comment: WDYF what are the best practices, is it worth to store into different indices even size is tiny? Basically we have 1 huge and all other very small ...

Comment: Having tiny indices would not effect your cluster performance if you use correct settings for number of shards. If you have a small indices you should set number of shards to one and for your bigger indices you can increase your shards number based on number of nodes you have.

Comment: But isn't it waste of 1 potential shard, because it could be 0-100 documents  only .. this shard can potentially serve other heavy indices .. correct?

Comment: One small shard is not a waste at all, but if you really want to use only one index you have another option called custom routing but this also will lead to store group of document on a specific shard. for more information check here:
https://www.elastic.co/blog/customizing-your-document-routing